# Issue with Div appearing based on selectbox selection Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5 Ruby 2.4.0 App that I am working on. A quick rundown of the workflow is a user selects a phone manufacturer, and is redirected to the respective "show" page, where they are met by a dynamically created selectbox with phone models, they select a model and a div appears below asking to confirm this is their device model.

As of current i have the select box, it populates (code below) however when I select a device the respective div dose not appear. I am not sure where i am going wrong weather it is the select box, div or javascript

> **My select Box is as follows:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="deviceSelect">Select Your <%= @manufacturer.name.titleize %> Device</label>
  <select class="form-control div-toggle" data-target=".device-names">
    <option>Select Device</option>
    <% @devices.each do |device| %>
      <option value="<%= device.device_name %>" data-show=".<%= device.device_name %>"><%= device.device_name.titleize %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
```

> **My Div is as follows:**

```
<div class="device-names">
  <% @devices.each do |device_div| %>
      <div class="<%= device_div.device_name %> invisible">
        <%= device_div.device_name %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> **My Javascript is as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
    $(target).children().addClass('invisible');
    $(show).removeClass('invisible');
  }):
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
  });
</script>
```

I don't appear to be getting any console errors and am unsure where I have gone wrong. I am also relatively new to javaScript, any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out I had a : instead of a ; and that was making the javaScript not run as it should have.